# Tools to use SQL Server is down

Tags: performance, tools

I have to go to multiple locations like SQL error log file, Event Log, run sp_whoisactive whenever I am have escalations from customers that SQL Server is slow. 
Is there any tool that will quickly give me a snapshot of all 3 in one(SQL Error logfile/Event(app log)/sp_whoisactive)

Comment: Why dont you invest in 3rd party tools like sentryone or redgate ? There is no out of box soution.

Answer (score 2):

The BrentOzar team's new PowerBI dashboard functionality for the First Responder kit is pretty awesome.  I use it every day to monitor/diagnose issues and it's super popular as an iPad/Surface dashboard.
https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/first-responder-kit-power-bi-dashboard/

**I should elaborate that I use their tools to gather data from many different servers into one central reporting server, and that's the one that runs the PowerBI Dashboard.  So I can monitor all of my servers at once and from the same dashboard using these features.  This means that if the offending server crashes, I can still monitor all details until (at most 15 minutes) right before it crashed.

Other than that, I've found Dell/Quest's Spotlight on SQL Server useful too.
https://www.quest.com/products/spotlight-on-sql-server-enterprise/

Comment: Thank you so much. I created a script
1. Can You Connect

Use master
SELECT * FROM sys.Databases 
2. Who is active ( Adam's script)
EXEC master.dbo.sp_whoisactive 
3. Find the Lead Blocker 
EXEC master.dbo.leadblocker
3. What’s in the SQL Server Error Log
***********************************************************/
EXEC xp_readerrorlog 0,1,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'desc'
/************************************************************/