# Approaches to prevent database slowdown when another process is hitting it hard

Tags: sql-server, performance

I'm a developer not a dba, but this task was given to me...

One of our databases is hit hard by a process which reads and modifies hundreds of thousands records onece or twice a day, during the time this process is running our other services who rely on this database get very slow.

What are some "common" approaches to solve this kind of problems?

Things I have thought that could work:

- Using "NOLOCK" in the read queries
- Using a cache service in front of the database, like Redis
- Using database redundancy

My questions are: Could any of these 3 options works? and if so, what kind of results can I expect. What other options do I have?

Comment: "reading" doesn't lock the tables or rows.

Comment: Unless you know _exactly_ what is going on in your database, anything you do will be like shooting yourself in the foot while blindfolded. If you can't hire a DBA, go [here](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/tree/main) and collect information first.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195694/tools-to-use-sql-server-is-down/195696#195696)

Comment: In addition you also might want to check this out for some really cool options https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2021/01/query-hints-you-can-use-to-avoid-blocking/

Comment: And let's add [bad habits - nolock everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere).

Comment: If you could post the**Execution Plans** (see [pastetheplan.com](https://www.pastetheplan.com) for your read and write queries that are running concurrently and causing issues we might be able to recommend good performance tuning measures you can take. Generally the `NOLOCK` query hint is recommended against (except in certain edge cases). Instead you can look into other isolation levels if you're going down that route. The other options you mentioned are valid solutions but without knowing your actual issue, I can't say for sure if they're a good solution.

Comment: Rewriting the other process will probably be the best option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. redesign/tune the procedure that is doing too much disk IO (or may too much use of cpu or ram)
2. increase hardware power (more MIOps, more ram, more logic cores)

But before doing so you have to deep dive into the issue to find what is the root cause of it.

Comment: I think we will be rewriting the process because I've recently looked into it in detail and it really is a mess

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, the problem you've outlined is very open-ended.  However, I can offer one general solution which you may not have considered: break up the intensive operation into smaller batches.  This will keep locks brief, reducing the risk of deadlocks, may reduce the amount of memory and temp space used, and may give the server enough headroom to cope while you do root cause analysis.

For example, if your overnight operation deletes a large number of records, you can instead run `DELETE TOP (10000) FROM X WHERE [blah blah]` in a loop while `@@NUMRECORDS > 0`.  You could throttle this by inserting a delay between executions.  Note that the *total* CPU cycles used will probably be greater with this approach; possibly dramatically greater, depending on the details of the queries involved.  If your server is short on memory, this approach could lead to thrashing your buffer pool (the cache recently-read or -modified records, held in memory when possible).  Test carefully before promoting any change to production, and be ready to halt and revert if it negatively impacts performance.